# Learn JSON to get value from web service in PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services

Anyone can segues me some site or tutorial related to how to get valuable data of JSON from WebSevice in PHP ?

Comment: I just start learn to work with project related WebService but i work in client. So i need to learn fast with how to get data from JSON. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$myObject=new MyObject();
$myObject->myString="example string";
$myObject->myInteger=5;
//etc..

echo json_encode($myObject);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation should be enough: [php json](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com';//YOUR WEB URL FROM WHERE YOU WANT TO FETCH/GET DATA
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true); // true is for array, false for objects

print_r($arr);
```

This will give you the associate array of "data shown on webservice" then you can get value by using array .

FOR EXAMPLE:

suppose the data at webservice at www.example.com is something like this:

```
<hotelinfo>
<hotel>
<name>abc hotel</name>
<city>Delhi</city>
</hotel>
</hotelinfo>
```

Then after print $arr as shown in codefor parse you get:

```
array(1) { ["hotelinfo"]=> array(1) { ["hotel"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(70)"abc hotel" ["city"] string(50) "delhi" .......
```

to use a particular value like hotel name you can do as follow:

```
$name=$arr['hotelinfo']['hotel']['name'];
```